# How do I achieve a clean cut of small circles?

Tags: sewing, quilting

Using a template for placement, how do I get a clean cut of 1/4, 3/4 and 1 inch holes in fabric? What tool would you recommend?

Comment: Hi nonnaisaquilter, I edited your question - since you tagged it with quilting, I assumed you want to cut these holes in fabric. If not, you can [edit](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/posts/8613/edit) the post yourself, or perform a rollback to the initial state. Welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Comment: The question wording has been edited and may imply a different meaning.  Is the question about how to cut/create the template, or how to cut the fabric?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could [edit] your question and describe what exactly you want to achieve. Any hole you cut into fabric will stretch and weaken the fabric in thar area. For example, if you want to put an 1 inch eyelet into a fabric and cut a 1 inch hole for it, the eyelet **will fall out** because the hole wil stretch. If you want a 1/4 inch hole, I wouldn't cut at all but gently push the threads aside until I could fit a 1/4 inch knitting needle through.

Comment: Hey everybody... edited the question so its not so confusing. OP can edit it back it so it is more confusing if they want but now it is answerable. Reopen?

Comment: @rebusB That's a possible interpretation, but we can't know what the OP intended until they clarify.

Comment: @Joachim - and one that makes sense here and would provide useful info for the site. If it doesn't work for the OP they can say so.

Comment: @rebusB That's true, but not how this process works. It sets a better example to have users ask well-written questions and interact with others posting comments than to have the community make something useful out of it and see what happens whenever the OP decides to show up again.

Comment: @Joachim - hopefully OP is paying attention then, however if they do feel this asks what they want what is "the process" for them to accept the rephrasing? Do they _have_ to edit it themselves? It seems like the goal should be good questions regardless and this is easily corrected. But I see where you are coming from now...

Answer (score 3):

You have an easy one, I think. The best tool for cutting the holes you describe, in template plastic is a hole punch, also known as a circle punch. A quick search shows that Amazon has all three sizes you describe.

3/4" - [EK Tools circle cutter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0090JVBP0)

1/4" - ["Conventional" hole punch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084ZJRQNH) - 0.25"

1" - [Cady crafts Punch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013NESBKK)

All of the above are amazon links and you can certainly find other resources, but this should give you a path to take.

Comment: The links are all for *paper* cutting tools. It seems unlikely that they would work on fabric.

Comment: Until the OP confirms the objective, the wording appears to reference cutting holes in plastic. Fabric can be cut with hole punches as long as the punch is not abused by cutting abrasive material. Our makerspace has similar items and are used with great results.

Comment: You have the right idea... just suggest going right to fabric punches and skipping the plastic step.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is a circle template, you can just buy a pre-made circle template like this (just a random example for illustration):

[image]
*<sup>Image courtesy [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004O4P030)</sup>*

They're widely available at office supply or art supply stores, big retailers, online merchants like Amazon, etc.

If you want to make your own, the best tool depends on the type of plastic you're working with.  Also, I'll assume that you would rather have a single tool or tool set with a range of sizes than a different type of tool for each size hole (which is often the case with the size range you describe).

**If the plastic is paper-thin**, and your idea is to pin or adhere the template to the fabric and then just cut the fabric around the guide, punches of the style described in [fred_dot_u's answer](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/8614/8251) are probably the way to go.  Just bear in mind that it will be easy to accidentally cut the template.

If your idea is to use a heavier template that provides an edge for marking the fabric, I'd suggest a different approach.  For a cardstock weight plastic, it might still be practical to use those kinds of punches.  But if you go to more substantial plastic, you'll want a different tool.  If the plastic you have in mind is a **heavier flexible plastic** sheet, like from a polypropylene looseleaf binder cover, a polypropylene coffee can lid, a polyethylene milk jug, or a PVC packaging clamshell, those punches won't be a good solution.  If they are capable of cutting the material without breaking or quickly wearing out, they will need a lot of leverage for a person of average strength to be able to punch such heavy materials.

If the plastic is thick enough to do well as a template (i.e., provides a useful edge), it will be easier to use a heavy duty punch designed for gaskets.  You can get sets covering your size range like this:

[image]
*<sup>Image courtesy [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00004T7WK)</sup>*

Check places like Amazon, Harbor Freight, or hardware stores; search on "gasket punch set".  Put the plastic on a flat, protective surface that will give and not damage the cutting edge, like a block of wood, position the punch, and whack the punch with a hammer.

If the plastic is thick enough to be like a commercially pre-made template (like the example at the start of the answer), it will be pretty **rigid** (and depending on the plastic, may be brittle).  You won't be able to punch the holes, you will need to cut or drill them.  The secret to cutting clean holes in plastic is to use a very sharp tool, cut slowly and without applying excessive force, and avoid building up heat (e.g., keep the surface wet), so the plastic doesn't soften and distort or melt.

There are hole saws that look like a circular band of saw blade, but they don't go down to your smaller hole sizes.  There are diamond hole saws that cover your size range, but the plastic will quickly melt and fill the abrasive edge.  There are a few kinds of bits that will work well on plastic.

One is a "step drill bit":

[image]
*<sup>Image courtesy [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076QC5BWR)</sup>*

These come with varying collections of hole sizes built into the bit.  You drill through the successively larger sizes until you have the hole size you want.

Another is a "spade bit":

[image]
*<sup>Image courtesy [Harbor Freight](https://www.harborfreight.com/steel-spade-drill-bit-set-13-pc-69028.html)</sup>*

As mentioned earlier, with either type of drill bit, it's important to not stress the plastic.  Use light pressure, go slow, and if practical, keep a puddle of water on the area (or even drill underwater in something like a basin).

Comment: Template plastic is actually an existing product that can be purchased, and is fairly thin so it can be cut by standard household scissors: https://www.joann.com/heavy-duty-plastic-templates/4793428.html I would guess this is the type of plastic the question refers to based on context.